# How to Prevent Copying PDF to Another Computer

Tags: php

I bought a book on leanpub.com. I am very interested in the technique that I can copy to the flashdisk, but the file can not be opened on another computer (I only seen white screen).
Does every person who sells at leanpub upload files that have been protected or leanpub.com create protected file at the runtime when people execute the link?
If it was created in runtime, how do I do it with PHP?

**Edit 1**
In simple word; I want to create a system to protect my pdf file in website just like leanpub. So, the people who have download the file, they can't copy easily to others.

**Edit 2**
Why people down vote? I don't think this is OOT. I am interesting to leanpub technique to protect the publisher right. I care about user right...
I have been searching http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php. But I can't solve it.

```
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode($the_file);   
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($the_file));
    //IS ANY POSSIBLE SOLUTION HERE TO ADD MORE HEADER TO PROTECT THE PUBLISHER RIGHT??
    flush(); 
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        echo fread($fp, 65536);
        flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    } 
    fclose($fp);
```

Above code add more header to current pdf file sending with url and force browser to download.
Is there any possible solution add more header to current pdf?

Answer (score 2):

You could [use TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt your flashdrive. That way, nobody will be able to get their hands on the contents of the drive without your passphrase.

Or you could use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to [password protect a .zip file](http://techfoxy.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-password-protect-your-files-with.html) that has the .pdf in it. That way, you would need the password in order to get to the file.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou for answering. It's seem misunderstand. Maybe because my english is bad. In simple word; I want to create a system to protect my pdf file in website just like leanpub. So, the people who have download the file, they can't copy easily to others.